# Center individual blocks that may wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a group of blocks that are not floated, but that have a set width and height and display `inline-block`.  Ideally, I would like for this entire block to be centered in the viewport.  See:

http://jsfiddle.net/hegQT/3/

The problem is that even if I make the outer div `inline-block` and it wraps to the width of the divs it contains, `margin: 0 auto` does not center.  `float`ing doesn't either, and I've tried a lot of other tactics too such as shrink wrapping the outer div to no avail.

The individual blocks cannot be floated.

`text-align: center` would work, but then if the last row has a different number of blocks, they will be centered themselves and I don't want that to happen.

This also needs to work without javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've grasp the exact functionality that you are looking for, but perhaps this will help: http://jsfiddle.net/ceSKJ/

Comment: Good effort, but the margin of the left-most block needs to be the same as the margin of the right-most block .. it's still flush left.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin: 0 auto;` needs a defined `width`. In my poor solution the `#outman` has `display: inline;` to get the real width and an additional `<div id="container">` has the auto margin. javascript is needed to set the real width to the new div:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="outman">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#outman {
    display: inline;
}
#outman div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').width($('#outman').width());
});
```

Also see my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/XznjK/).

=== UPDATE ===

It will be faster if you move the script directly after the container in the html code and remove the `$(document).ready()`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="outman">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#container').width($('#outman').width());
</script>
```

Also see my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/XznjK/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

With window resize:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#container').css('width', 'auto');
    $('#container').width($('#outman').width());
});
</script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<div id="container">
    <div id="outman">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize();
</script>
...
</body>
```

And a [new example](http://jsfiddle.net/XznjK/2/).

Comment: This is a good javascript solution, but I can't do it with javascript.  The problem is that the page takes a noticeable amount of time to load (about 1 second) and javascript only fires on `document.ready`, so the blocks will appear to snap to the middle after the fact.

Comment: I've updated my answer and hope that this time can be reduced significantly.